# Where should I install SQL Management Server instances on my development machine?

Tags: docker, ssms, hyper-v

I have a new desktop Windows 10 development machine and am trying to minimize what I install on it.

On my old development machine I wound up with multiple versions of SQL Server and Management Studio.

This time I have installed SQL Server in a docker container.

Because of the answer to  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092112/can-should-docker-be-used-for-winforms-applications) I understand I should not put Management Studio in a container.  So where should I put it.  In Hyper-V ?

Comment: Is this a desktop or server?

Comment: I updated the question to show it is a windows 10 desktop machine

Comment: What do you think would be gained by putting SSMS in a container or Hyper-V VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why  "minimize" your installation and put barriers between yourself and your work? The purpose of a development machine is to have all the necessary tools to do your job at your disposal.

There's nothing wrong with having multiple versions of SQL Server or Management Studio installed on a single development machine, unless you're short on disk space. And there is no need to containerize them or put them in separate VMs.

I would, however, recommend installing them in the order they were released (oldest to newest). In the past, I've had as many as four releases of SQL Server installed on a single development machine, along with their corresponding SSMS (because until 2016, SSMS always came along for the ride). No troubles.

Comment: I have heard that Visual Studio runs significantly slower if lots of things are installed.

Comment: @kirsteng can't say that I've heard or seen anything like that. The presence of other programs on a PC has little to no impact on performance unless they're running (side note: if you have SQL Server installed on your workstation, set the services to manual startup so it isn't running when you don't need it). You will, however, see a performance hit by running everything in virtual machines unless you've got a high-end PC - at which point the "I've heard..." argument about performance with lots of things being installed also evaporates.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your Management Studio in your Hyper-V.
From docker expose the ports of SQL server.

After this you should be able to connect to the SQL server running inside your docker.
If required to use some hostname (is management studio needs it) then edit the host file and add the hostname and IP address as docker IP address so that your management studio contacts the docker.